# Anacron, prevent multiple executions in the same same day

Tags: cron

Is there a way to prevent anacron to run a job that was already completed the same day and it's being executed again just because the machine was rebooted?

Comment: IMO this is not a problem of cron but the way you use it. Provide the cron records for this task

Comment: @RomeoNinov there is no cron, I think I clearly stated I'm using Anacron.

Comment: What is you config of anacron. how do you define this job?

Comment: @RomeoNinov please forgive me if i doubt about the relevance of your question,  considering you can't tell the difference between one program and the other.

Comment: Anyway, it's @daily 5 backup /bin/bash /my_backup_script

Comment: AFAIK in case of restart anacron do not keep track of already executed jobs. You can keep track in your script by keep in one file the date on which it is executed and check if current date is the same.

Comment: It seems, it worth to check the logs. Possibly [on unix system], to review 'syslog'  and do 'grep "cron"' or similar for some last hundreds records there.